# SqlAdapter Update() only inserts values.

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have table called Inventory, and I want to remove the first row of it. For that purpose I have created a class named InventoryDAL. Here's code:

```
public class InventoryDAL
{
    private string cnString = string.Empty;
    private SqlDataAdapter da = null;

    public InventoryDAL(string connectionString)
    {
        cnString = connectionString;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select CarID, Make, Color, PetName From Inventory",
            connectionString);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
        da.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
        da.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
    }

    public DataTable Inventory()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

    public void UpdateInventory(DataTable modifiedTable)
    {
        da.Update(modifiedTable);
    }
}
```

Also I created small program to try it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InventoryDAL inv = new InventoryDAL(@"Data Source=MYPC;Initial Catalog=AutoLot;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        DataTable dt = inv.Inventory();
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
        inv.UpdateInventory(dt);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }}
```

But it's not working. After some attempts I realized that `.Update()` works only when I insert data.

Comment: Don;t you need a primary key defined to edit/delete rows?

Comment: Where do you define your connection string and the delete/update/insert commands?  Also, you should really consider using [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @DStanley I actually primary key is set in table. It is the CarID column. I tried to explicitly specify it like this: 
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns[0] }; 
but it is still don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DataTable.RemoveAt() completely removes the row from a DataTable object, so the SqlDataAdapter doesn't know to delete it at the data source. You have to use the DataTable.Rows[x].Delete() method. This marks the row for deletion so the adapter then knows to call the SQL delete statement on it.

So your code should become:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InventoryDAL inv = new InventoryDAL(@"Data Source=MYPC;Initial Catalog=AutoLot;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        DataTable dt = inv.Inventory();
        dt.Rows[0].Delete();
        inv.UpdateInventory(dt);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y.aspx) for more on how changes get pushed back to the data source.